# How do I change bookmarks into desktop icons?

Tags: icons, bookmarks

I have just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 (yesterday) and can't figure out how to put application icons on the desktop for bookmarks. I have making bookmarks pretty much down, but can't figure out how to move them to the desktop as icons. There must be a way to do it, but I'll be darned if I can figure it out. Please help a super beginner.

Comment: Do you mean links to *applications* or links to webpages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome or Firefox, you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then find the bookmark you want and drag it to your desktop.

Comment: Nice, works for Firefox bookmarks though the link opens in Chromium... (Firefox is defaukt)

Comment: @Wilf Hmm, is Chromium your default browser? If so, try changing it to Firefox.

Comment: @Wilf try this: Right-click the bookmark, go to properties, "open with" and choose firefox there.

Comment: tried that as well - never mind...